# Mininet - Exec curl from javascript file

Tags: curl, mininet

how to execute curl from javascript file in mininet? Can you please show me how to execute for example this command:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"match": {"nw_dst": "10.0.0.1", "nw_proto": "UDP", "tp_dst": "5002"}, "actions":{"queue": "1"}}' http://localhost:8080/qos/rules/0000000000000001
```

Answer (score 0):

"curl" is not a mininet command. Instead, it is a shell command, so you need to use "sh" command of Mininet to execute "curl".

I haven't tried, but it should look like:

```
sh curl -X POST -d '{"match": {"nw_dst": "10.0.0.1", "nw_proto": "UDP", "tp_dst": "5002"}, "actions":{"queue": "1"}}' http://localhost:8080/qos/rules/0000000000000001
```

If there is anything wrong, please tell me.